# Why can I not use the quadratic formula here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

$x^2-14x+49$

I tried applying the quadratic formula here, but I end up with $14 ± 0$ which makes no sense.

I am supposed to factor the above mentioned expression and I thought the quadratic formula would be appropriate. Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't make sense? You have a double zero. [You should somewhere still divide by $2$.]

Comment: On my website, I give an example of completing the square. http://mathuprising.comlu.com/special-products-case-study.html  . Try it with $x^2-14x+49$, and then again with $ax^2+bx+c$

Comment: b^2-4ac=0 is zero in this case. you will get same roots.

Answer (score 3):

There is an error, It is a perfect square $ (x-7)^2,$ both factors are same.The roots are $ 7, 7. $

EDIT1:

You can very well use the quadratic solution formula here. Using the same, you should get $\dfrac{14±0}{2} $ but you forgot dividing by 2 , and got $ 14\pm 0 $  only, double the value of double root that you ought to have got.

Comment: "There is an error" - What? There's no error.

Comment: You should get $ \dfrac{14\pm 0}{2} $ but you forgot dividing by 2 and got $ 14\pm 0$ only, double the value of double root that you ought to have got.

Comment: Oh lol okay, that's what you were referring to. Maybe you could made that more explicit in your post.

Comment: transferred comment to the post..

Answer (score 3):

\begin{array}{*{20}c} {x = \frac{{ - b \pm \sqrt {b^2 - 4ac} }}{{2a}}} & {{\rm{when}}} & {ax^2 + bx + c = 0} \\ \end{array}

In your case:
$a=1, b=-14, c=49\;$ so you get:

$$x=\frac{-(-14)\pm \sqrt{(-14)^2 -4*1*49}}{2*1}$$

$$x=14/2=7$$.

$$f(x)=(x-7)(x-7)$$

Comment: I appear to have missed the fact that the entire expression is the numerator and not just the square root. 14/2 = 7. Makes sense now.

Still not entirely sure how I apply this in factoring the expression, though. Any leads? :)

Comment: @julian If the roots of a quadratic polynomial are $a$ and $b$, then it factors as $(x-a)(x-b)$.

Comment: Once you get the root (or roots), you write your function as $f(x)=(x-r1)(x-r2)$ That is in this case, since both roots are equal, you write $f(x)=(x-7)*(x-7)$

Comment: I think it is kind of misleading to use x both for the variable in $f(x)$ and for the root value. However, this is very common. Maybe we should use root1 and root2, then the factors become (x-root1)(x-root2).

Comment: If $r$ and $s$ are the roots, *and the coefficient of $x^2$ is $1$*, then the polynomial factors as $(x-r)(x-s)$.